# How to filter on dictionary with multiples keys

Tags: dictionary, filter, key

I have a dictionnary with double key which look like this:

{('Year', 'prix'): 130546.87449454193,

('Year', 'departement'): 11591.47409694357,

('Year', 'annee'): 34.28496633835407,

('Year', 'kilometrage'): 414330.13854019763,

('price', 'prix'): 324162.66684322944,

('price', 'departement'): 466290.81724082783,

('price', 'annee'): 454736.63137143303,

('price', 'kilometrage'): 117557.09720242623}

I want to filter only on the first part of my key which is a tuple. In other words I want to get this result if I specify in my code 'Year':

{('Year', 'prix'): 130546.87449454193,

('Year', 'departement'): 11591.47409694357,

('Year', 'annee'): 34.28496633835407,

('Year', 'kilometrage'): 414330.13854019763}

I reached my result, but only after multiple lines of code. I am wondering if there is a way to do it smoothly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
# Suppose you have your dict stored in dct
# The line below returns a filtered dictionary, including keys with first tuple element 'Year'
{key: dct[key] for key in dct.keys() if key[0]=='Year'}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is the answer I was looking for. Thank you abe!